# How do we "order by" filtering order

Tags: sql, mariadb

What is the trick that we can do in order to a SQL Query be ordered by the ID's we inject in the `in` clause?

like:

```
select oh.orderID, oh.orderType, oh.state, oh.orderDateTime
from orderHeaders oh 
where oh.orderID in (
47185154,
47185121,
47184971,
47863101)
```

my `orderID` field comes like:

```
47184971...
47863101...
47185121...
47185154...
```

how can get the result ordered by the entries ordering in the `WHERE IN (...)` filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `field()`:

```
select oh.orderID, oh.orderType, oh.state, oh.orderDateTime
from orderHeaders oh 
where oh.orderID in (47185154, 47185121, 47184971, 47863101)
order by field(oh.orderID, 47185154, 47185121, 47184971, 47863101);
```

Comment: darn! I learn one new thing today, **thank you** so much! this is being troubled me for ages and only now took the time to actually ask for it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define them in the order by clause

```
ORDER BY
CASE oh.OrderID 
WHEN '47185154' THEN 1
WHEN '47185121' THEN 2
WHEN '47184971' THEN 3
WHEN '47863101' THEN 4
ELSE 5
END
```